# urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection...: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, connection, urllib3

Full message:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='example-for-this-question.com', port=5002): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f8522fe0c40>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname')
```

Occurs seemingly randomly during successful processing of thousands of requests.post calls to the same hostname:port.

Could this be a dns or other network-related problem?